# How to write Linq or Lambda expression for nested collections

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, nested

I know simple linq, but here the problem statement has multiple level of nesting. How to write Linq or Lambda expression for nested collections.

**Input Object Definition:**

```
public class Service
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Service> ChildServices{ get; set; }

    public List<Action> AvailableActions{ get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Parameters{ get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The nesting can go to multiple levels

**Linq Expected Output**

here I need to write Linq or Lambda expression which

1. Gets all the Services
2. Get service with a given name

Comment: Nothing about your output would require accessing the collections defined - unless I am misunderstanding something here - `from s in Service select s` and `from s in Service where s.Name == specifiedValue select s`

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that you start with a list of services, like this:

```
var services = new List<Service>()
{
    new Service()
    {
        Name = "A",
        ChildServices = new List<Service>()
        {
            new Service() { Name = "C", ChildServices = new List<Service>() },
            new Service()
            {
                Name = "D",
                ChildServices = new List<Service>()
                {
                    new Service() { Name = "E", ChildServices = new List<Service>() },
                    new Service() { Name = "F", ChildServices = new List<Service>() },
                }
            },
        }
    },
    new Service()
    {
        Name = "B",
        ChildServices = new List<Service>()
        {
            new Service() { Name = "G", ChildServices = new List<Service>() },
            new Service() { Name = "H", ChildServices = new List<Service>() },
        }
    },
};
```

Which looks like this:

[image: services]

Then this query will flatten the list out:

```
Func<IEnumerable<Service>, IEnumerable<Service>> traverse = null;
traverse = ss =>
    from s in ss
    from s2 in new [] { s }.Concat(traverse(s.ChildServices))
    select s2;
```

Calling `traverse(services)` returns this:

[image: flattened]

You can then look-up a service by name using a normal LINQ query or you could make a dictionary like this:

```
var serviceByName = traverse(services).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

var serviceG = serviceByName["G"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is direct way to recursively query nested collection (Atleast I'm aware).

Below solution might work for your cases.

```
public class Service
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Service> ChildServices{ get; set; }

    public List<Action> AvailableActions{ get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Parameters{ get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {

    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Service> GetAllServices(this Service node)
    {
        yield return node;
        if(node.ChildServices != null)
        {
            foreach(var child in node.ChildServices)
            {
                foreach(var childOrDescendant in child.GetAllServices())
                {
                    yield return childOrDescendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working fiddler [Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LF7V7b)